# GSON "NoClassDefFoundError com/google/gson/Gson"

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to get gson to work on a java project, but get the above error every time I run it. I am not using any flash IDEs, just vim and every question I have seen related to my question is to do with eclipse and their deployment settings. I hope someone can spot something wrong in my tactics.

Note: I have the gson jar file renamed to gson.jar

To compile my code:
`javac myProgram.java -cp gson.jar`
and to run my code:
`java myProgram -cp gson.jar`

The program will compile fine, but it will throw an error as soon as I attempt to initiliaze a `Gson` object.

Full error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you have the javac and java argument order mixed up. The syntax is:

```
javac <options> <source files>
```

and

```
java [-options] class [args...]
```

So it should be something like

```
javac -cp gson.jar myProgram.java
```

Same goes for the `java` command.

Answer (score 0):

Include the present directory location of *myProgram* or compiled java class. So run;

```
java -cp gson.jar:. myProgram
```

The dot assumes you are running myProgram from the same dir location it is place. Else use "full path to myProgram". [Aleksander Stojadinovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794967/aleksandar-stojadinovic) is also right, the order of things matters with the java runtime environment!